# Access other function elements

Tags: php, php-7

So, I have two functions. The first is to activate the game bonuses and other is to show all of them in templates.

```
public function send()
{
    $reduct = (1 - $CONF['reduc_numb'] / 100);
}
```

Second function:

```
function show()
{
    $this->tplObj->assign_vars(array('bonus' => $USER_bonus));
}
```

My question is how can I access `$reduct` element in function show and assign it to my template file?

Comment: make session of $reduct

Comment: Is that first function a class method?

Comment: And is the second function just a function i.e. NOT a class method

Comment: Sorry i cant give you a proper answer on this because my php knowledge is primitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally, it's not possible. Here's why... At a time, only one function will get executed. And the local variables inside each function will be cleared after that function completes it's execution. Here's 2 of the ways you can accomplish your goal.

1. **Use a global variables so that both of these functions can access it.**

   You can declare the variable `$reduct` as a global variable and make `send()` store the computed value to the global variable `$reduct`, so that `show()` can access it too. In this case, your code becomes:

   `$reduct;
   function send(){
       global $reduct;
       $reduct = (1 - $CONF['reduc_numb'] / 100);
   }
   function show(){
       global $reduct;
       $this->tplObj->assign_vars(array('bonus' => $USER_bonus)); //$reduct is available
   }`
2. **Call `send()` from inside `show()`**

   This method is quite simple. As your function `send()` already returns `$reduct`, call `send()` from inside `show()` and use the value returned by `send()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your both function send() and show() in same class then

You can call send() function in show() function like below

```
public function send()
{
    $reduct = (1 - $CONF['reduc_numb'] / 100);

    return $reduct;
}

function show()
    {
   $reduct = $this->send();
   $this->tplObj->assign_vars(array(
        'bonus'  => $USER_bonus,
        'reduct' => $reduct

    ));
 }
```

Comment: My send function are 50 line long, with lot of other values and variables, so i guess this wont work that way.  
For better example i have $reduct , $WBR, $User_ip  etc. in my send function

Comment: Then you have to store it in session or make seperate function for reduct

Comment: If you're just learning PHP or programming in general you can simply return an array with multiple values instead of one with this approach. Or create a custom class with all the attributes you need to share between the functions. E.g. `return [ $reduct,  $WBR, $User_ip];`

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
return $reduct;
```

To your public function. And when you call this function like,

```
echo your_function(and, variables, here);
```

It will act like a variable so you can use it.